# Kubernetes service endpoints IP with hostnetwork and two networks on host

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have some hosts with 2 interfaces. Also, I have deamonset with hostnetwork and service for it. Kubernetes uses one interface for work, but my app uses other.

In the service endpoints I see the IP of the first interface, how can I change it to the second IP without changing the endpoint manifest by hand?

Answer (score 0):

The brief explanation of ways to access Kubernetes Pods from outside of the cluster can be found [here](http://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/).

Only the `Nodeport` option allows you to select the desired interface.

There is a kube-proxy flag for selecting NodePort IP range introduced by [PR #58052](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/58052).

You can find more information in the [design-proposals](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/network/nodeport-ip-range.md) and the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport):

> If you want to specify particular IP(s) to proxy the port, you can set the `--nodeport-addresses` flag in kube-proxy to particular IP block(s) (which is supported since Kubernetes v1.10). A comma-delimited list of IP blocks (e.g. `10.0.0.0/8`, `1.2.3.4/32`) is used to filter addresses local to this node. For example, if you start kube-proxy with flag `--nodeport-addresses=127.0.0.0/8`, kube-proxy will select only the loopback interface for NodePort Services. The --nodeport-addresses is defaulted to empty `([])`, which means select all available interfaces and is in compliance with current NodePort behaviors.